# Calling HTTPS APIs from HTTP pages via javascript

Tags: php, javascript, security, https, authorization

I have a landing page on http://example.com ;that has an ajax login bar on it, which sends the user's login to the server, receives the authentication response, and displays it to the user.

The problem with this approach, is that user login information is sent in cleartext to the server, without SSL encryption. However, when doing the same POST request to https://example.com, NGINX responds with 401 Unauthorized.

In what ways might we be able to use https://example.com/user_api as the authorization URL?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should really be using https for the entire site, including the landing page.  Don't allow regular http.  If you were doing this, the problem you are having would be gone.

The reason why you should use https for the entire site even though there is no sensitive data  on the landing page is because encrypting the communication is only half of what SSL does.  The other half (which is just as important for protecting your users) is identification of the server.  When the site is retrieved using https, the identification of the remote server is verified by examining it's certificate, which is signed with its private key.  This certificate is verified against a trusted third party, so the user knows they are indeed speaking with your server.

If you don't use https for your whole site, you are making it trivial for a malicious server to impersonate your site and harvest your user's credentials.  Even better, because of this design, they can log your users in to your app and forward them to the right page, nobody the wiser!

Another reason is that when big teams are working on a web app, it is easy for someone to accidentally create a page that should be secure but uses http instead.  This can be a big security hole.

Please consider a redesign to use https for your whole site.  It is more work up front but the security payoffs are huge.

Comment: What if your hosting doesn't allow https? (like mine...)